# Nullability of KeyValuePair<string string> is not as expected

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

While inspecting the nullability of they `Key` and `Value` properties of `KeyValuePair<string, string>`, I stumbled upon that they are nullable although declared as `string` and not as `string?`.

```
var type = typeof(KeyValuePair<string, string>);
var keyProperty = type.GetProperty(nameof(KeyValuePair<string, string>.Key)) ?? throw new Exception("key property not found");
var valueProperty = type.GetProperty(nameof(KeyValuePair<string, string>.Value)) ?? throw new Exception("value property not found");

var nullabilityInfoContext = new NullabilityInfoContext();
var keyNullability = nullabilityInfoContext.Create(keyProperty);
var valueNullability = nullabilityInfoContext.Create(valueProperty);

Console.WriteLine(keyNullability.ReadState); // Expected: NotNull, Actual: Nullable
Console.WriteLine(keyNullability.WriteState); // Expected: Unknown, Actual: Unknown
Console.WriteLine(valueNullability.ReadState); // Expected: NotNull, Actual: Nullable
Console.WriteLine(valueNullability.WriteState); // Expected: Unknown, Actual: Unknown
```

Nullable reference types are turned on in the project through

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

in the csproj file.

Why are they nullable although they are not declared as `string?`?

Comment: probably Nullable Reference Types feature is enabled in project level . You can disable it  <Nullable>disable</Nullable>

Comment: Nullable reference types is turned on globally in my sproj file. Otherwise getting Nullable would be expected.

Comment: Note that the same thing happens if you declare a custom `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`, so this is not a restriction or omission on `KeyValuePair` specifically. It's more likely a limitation of `NullabilityInfoContext` with regards to (instantiated) generics, since the same does not happen for a non-generic type, and annotating the type parameter with `notnull` yields the expected result. Nullability not truly being a first-class citizen of the runtime is probably interfering here.

Comment: According to the reference source, `KeyValuePair` is defined as `public struct KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`, and was not compiled with nullable reference types enabled.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty interesting! As I'm not a Microsoft engineer, I really don't know, but please see my following example:

```cs
#nullable enable

[Fact]
public void NullabilityTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var type = typeof(Tralala);
    var nullabilityInfoContext = new NullabilityInfoContext();

    // Act
    var nullabilityOfNullable = nullabilityInfoContext.Create(type.GetProperty(nameof(Tralala.Nullable))!);
    var nullabilityOfNotNullable = nullabilityInfoContext.Create(type.GetProperty(nameof(Tralala.NotNullable))!);

    // Assert
    nullabilityOfNullable.ReadState.Should().Be(NullabilityState.Nullable);
    nullabilityOfNullable.WriteState.Should().Be(NullabilityState.Nullable);
    nullabilityOfNotNullable.ReadState.Should().Be(NullabilityState.NotNull);
    nullabilityOfNotNullable.WriteState.Should().Be(NullabilityState.NotNull);
}

public class Tralala
{
    public string NotNullable { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Nullable { get; set; }
}
```

This test passes. Therefore I assume that `Key` and `Value` of `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` are indeed nullable.

<s>Maybe Microsoft hasn't introduced Nullable Reference Types for `KeyValuePair`? At least I don't see any `#nullable enable` in the file itself and I didn't find the corresponding `csproj` setting.</s>

**Update**
I'm getting the impression that it's related to generics, because the following code fails:

```cs
[Fact]
public void NullabilityTestWithGeneric()
{
    // Arrange
    var type = typeof(Tralala<string>);
    var nullabilityInfoContext = new NullabilityInfoContext();

    // Act
    var nullabilityOfKey = nullabilityInfoContext.Create(type.GetProperty("Key")!);

    // Assert
    nullabilityOfKey.ReadState.Should().Be(NullabilityState.NotNull);
}

public class Tralala<T>
{
    public T Key { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

But this one works:

```cs
[Fact]
public void NullabilityTestWithGeneric()
{
    // Arrange
    var type = typeof(Tralala<string>);
    var nullabilityInfoContext = new NullabilityInfoContext();

    // Act
    var nullabilityOfKey = nullabilityInfoContext.Create(type.GetProperty("Key")!);

    // Assert
    nullabilityOfKey.ReadState.Should().Be(NullabilityState.NotNull);
}

public class Tralala<T> where T : notnull
{
    public T Key { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

Probably that's related to some sort of backwards compatibility. I think it could be worth opening an issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/KeyValuePair.cs) and ask Microsoft directly.

Answer (score 0):

This  is my thought. There are some known pitfalls  in case of arrays and structs. In both situations, a non-nullable reference may be initialized to null, without generating warnings. It is mentioned in

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#:~:text=Nullable%20contexts%20enable%20fine%2Dgrained,context%20determines%20the%20compiler's%20behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#:%7E:text=Nullable%20contexts%20enable%20fine%2Dgrained,context%20determines%20the%20compiler%27s%20behavior).

Since KeyValuePair is a struct type it is showing as Nullable. May be below code snippet clarify that.

```
 var nameProperty = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                       .GetType(typeof(Person).FullName)
                       .GetProperty("Name");

 var studentName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                       .GetType(typeof(Student).FullName)
                       .GetProperty("FirstName");

 var keyProperty = typeof(KeyValuePair<string, string>)
                .GetProperty("Key");

 var nullabilityInfoContext = new NullabilityInfoContext();
 var NameNullable = nullabilityInfoContext.Create(nameProperty);
 var KeyNullable = nullabilityInfoContext.Create(keyProperty);
 var FullNameNullable = nullabilityInfoContext.Create(keyProperty);

 Console.WriteLine(NameNullable.ReadState); 
 Console.WriteLine(NameNullable.WriteState);
 Console.WriteLine(KeyNullable.ReadState);
 Console.WriteLine(KeyNullable.WriteState);
 Console.WriteLine(FullNameNullable.ReadState);
 Console.WriteLine(FullNameNullable.WriteState);
```

In above code Student is struct and Person is class. The output for both KeyvaluePair and Student are  same.

Thank you.